# Shuffle Array -> Request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: arrays, c, struct, shuffle

I have this code that will generate all possible splits of a deck of cards

```
void divide(CardDeck origDeck, CardDeck * leftDeck, CardDeck * rightDeck)
{
  int size = origDeck.size - 1 ;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < size; size++){
    int midpoint = i + 1;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while (j < midpoint){
      leftDeck.cards[j] = origDeck.cards[j];
      j++;
    }
    int remaining = origDeck.size - j;
    while (k < remaining){
      rightDeck.cards[k] = origDeck.cards[j];
      k++;
      j++;
    }
    void interleave(CardDeck leftDeck, CardDeck rightDeck);
  }
```

However I keep getting this error here. I've tried replacing the -> with the dot operator, but it still gives another error

```
gcc -std=c99 -g -Wall -Wshadow --pedantic -Wvla -Werror -DTEST_INTERLEAVE -DTEST_DIVIDE -DTEST_SHUFFLE -c shuffle.c 
shuffle.c: In function ‘divide’:
shuffle.c:52:15: error: request for member ‘cards’ in something not a structure or union
       leftDeck.cards[j] = origDeck.cards[j];
               ^
shuffle.c:57:16: error: request for member ‘cards’ in something not a structure or union
       rightDeck.cards[k] = origDeck.cards[j];
                ^
make: *** [shuffle.o] Error 1
```

This is the error that I receive upon replacing the . with arrow operators

```
shuffle.c: In function ‘divide’:
shuffle.c:52:36: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘CardDeck’)
       leftDeck->cards[j] = origDeck->cards[j];
                                    ^
shuffle.c:57:37: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘CardDeck’)
       rightDeck->cards[k] = origDeck->cards[j];
                                     ^
make: *** [shuffle.o] Error 1
bash-4.2$
```

For the header file, it looks like this:

```
#ifndef SHUFFLE_H
#define SHUFFLE_H
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 13

typedef struct
{
  char cards[MAX_SIZE];
  int size;
} CardDeck;

void divide(CardDeck origDeck, CardDeck* leftDeck, CardDeck* rightDeck);
void interleave(CardDeck leftDeck, CardDeck rightDeck);
void shuffle (CardDeck origDeck);
```

Comment: `->` is correct. If you get another error then show it. Also, we need complete code. Please provide it as a [mre].

Comment: what is `CardDeck` ? Have you included right header file ?

Comment: `leftDeck.cards[j] = origDeck.cards[j];` --> `leftDeck->cards[j] = origDeck.cards[j];`

Comment: `origDeck` is an instance of a structure, so you use dot `.` notation, e.g. `origDeck.cards[j]`. `leftDeck` and `rightDeck` are **pointers** to structures, so you use arrow `->` notation, e.g. `leftDeck->cards[j]`

Comment: What do you expect the following line to do? `void interleave(CardDeck leftDeck, CardDeck rightDeck);`

Comment: Edited to show the other error message

Comment: For the interleave function, it is supposed to interleave two decks to generate all possible results. So the nested loops are to generate all possible splits of a deck. Then interleave is called to generate all possible orders for cards for each split

Comment: `void interleave(CardDeck leftDeck, CardDeck rightDeck);` at the end of `divide` is nonsense, you are missing one final brace at the end and you don't include the header file. Fixing those things, the modified code with pointers does not give the error you claim it does. Maybe some silly error like you forgetting to save the file before compiling? Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

change `origDeck` to a pointer

```
void divide(CardDeck *origDeck, CardDeck *leftDeck, CardDeck *rightDeck)
```

and

```
leftDeck->cards[j] = origDeck->cards[j];
rightDeck->cards[k] = origDeck->cards[j];
```